# Failed install Rabbitmq (3.9) server does not startup because it needs older ssl library required by Erlang running on Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, erlang, ubuntu-20.04

I'm setting up a new server on Ubuntu 20.04.4 I installed rabbitmq and when starting up the service I'm hitting an error:  Failed to load NIF library /usr/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-5.0.5/priv/lib/crypto After some investigation I found that Erlang is requiring an older version of ssl (esl-erlang Depends libssl1.0.0 | libssl1.0.2 | libssl1.1) I can get around the problem by installing the 1.0.0 ssl version, but my question is why is this failing?  Seems like it would be better to not require the older ssl, but I have not found a way to get around that.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can download rabbitmq source code and compile it in your computer. It will use your local crypto version.

If you use prebuild rabbitmq version， it depends one the precondition version, so the conflict problem appear.